# Upload Special Characters

Tags: magento2, product, error, csv, upload

I am trying to upload all my products but I keep getting errors.

I have them with special Characters, When I check the data it is valid and good.

With the next one I get this error:
[image]

Please let me know what to do, I made all the categories so I dont get the problem.

Comment: Only require changing URL key for all products/category. Because URL is unique for all. If you change your URL key after that you can't get this type of error. **@Maarten**

Answer (score 1):

The error says, the category with the name "" was not created, because the url key already exists. I don't know wether this can only be a category or a product/cms page.

So to fix your problem:
Check your data, look for a category without a name and make sure the URL key doesn't already exist (which might be "").

A problem which might exist inside your problem: You can't see the category which is blocking your insert, because it is inside a MySQL transaction, so you can't see the first insert.